# What is the limit of the Box-Cox transformation as lambda goes to 0?

Tags: data-transformation

I am running into this problem and was told this could help.

Comment: The Box-Cox transformation with parameter $\lambda$ is $$x\to \int_1^x y^{\lambda-1}\mathrm{d}y.$$ There's no need to take a limit: simply set $\lambda=0.$

Answer (score 4):

For parameter values $\lambda \neq 0$ the [Box-Cox transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box%E2%80%93Cox_transformation) is:

$$y^{(\lambda)} = \frac{y^\lambda-1}{\lambda}.$$

Taking limits and applying [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) gives:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\lim_{\lambda \rightarrow 0} y^{(\lambda)}
&= \lim_{\lambda \rightarrow 0} \frac{y^\lambda-1}{\lambda} \\[6pt]
&= \lim_{\lambda \rightarrow 0} \frac{(\ln y) y^\lambda}{1} \\[6pt]
&= \ln y \times \lim_{\lambda \rightarrow 0} y^\lambda \\[6pt]
&= \ln y. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

In order to preserve continuity of the function, by convention, we define the Box-Cox transform at $\lambda = 0$ by its limit:

$$y^{(0)} \equiv \lim_{\lambda \rightarrow 0} y^{(\lambda)} = \ln y.$$

This is one possible way to look at the Box-Cox transformation.  As [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/) points out in the comment above, the Box-Cox transformation can actually be defined for all cases by the following integral:

$$y^{(\lambda)} \equiv \int \limits_1^y r^{\lambda-1} dr.$$

This definition is well-defined for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and reduces directly to the stipulated form when $\lambda =0$.